# Regex Pattern Needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

hope someone is able to help out finding this regex pattern:
If i have this requests:

```
1-15 20241 0/0/6205 W 1.13 1071 0 0.00 11138.15 118.100.162.102 domain.com:443 GET /file/192493511503562/ HTTP/1.1

2-15 6252 0/130/6078 W 5.50 387 0 0.0 490.28 16798.43 14.33.181.155 domain.com:443 GET /file/720658522052690/ HTTP/1.1

3-14 9649 0/157/5992 G 4.37 1807 0 0.0  296.81 13625.69 212.252.56.41 domain.com:443 GET /file/512530584447085/ HTTP/1.1
```

another sample output (by source code)

```
0-16 1005 0/59/6014 W 2.15 648 0 0.0 114.91 10535.48 178.235.43.134   domain.com:443 GET /file/152577842120081/ HTTP/1.1   1-16 8820 0/22/6489 W 0.96 1790 0 0.0 100.79 11996.02 177.221.26.229   domain.com:443 GET /file/415757652884349/ HTTP/1.1   2-16 28288 0/35/6723 W 1.46 178 0 0.0 68.29 18010.46 89.3.212.185   domain.com:443 GET /file/687013016222044/ HTTP/1.1   3-16 10274 0/0/6736 W 0.07 2275 0 0.0 0.00 14280.77 46.176.105.15   domain.com:443 GET /file/321646937401965/ HTTP/1.1   4-16 29945 0/2/7471 W 0.02 210 0 0.0 0.01 16350.10 190.158.29.250   domain.com:443 GET /file/333674884214997/ HTTP/1.1   5-16 29245 0/2/7699 W 0.01 272 0 0.0 1.07 20284.17 49.48.250.12   domain.com:443 GET /file/781792728276923/ HTTP/1.1
```

There is just one space between. 
I need to get those values:

```
20241   
192493511503562

6252  
720658522052690

9649
512530584447085
```

So currently my preg_match_all looks like:

```
preg_match_all('@[0-9] (.*?) [0-9]/@si', $output, $url) ;  
foreach($url[1] as $output )  {  echo $output ; }
```

How can i get both values? The current preg_match only echos the first value. So for example  20241  6252 .. etc. I tried this

```
preg_match_all('@[0-9] (.*?) [0-9]*/(.*?)/@si', $output, $url) ; 
foreach($url[0] as $output )  {   echo $output ; }
```

but still not the result i want with [0]. Maybe some of your genuise people can help out.

EDIT: 
To clarify this is the output from exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl fullstatus', $output); foreach ($output as $output )  {  and the code } ..
So i just need the PID and REQUEST of an apache process

Comment: You should try to use a tool like: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Also, what are you expecting `$url[0]` to contain?

Comment: believe me i tried 1000 of variants on my life php script, the url you provided is just a live viewer.. but thanks anyway

Comment: This looks like a system log, there are probably parsers out there for it. To start though `[0-9]` is only looking for one number. A `+` or `*` would allow for multiple numbers; those are `quantifiers`.

Comment: yes it is from apache status, however these are ident or similair, especially this is the same on every request -XX VALUE1 XX/XX/XX for the first value and the second file/VALUE2/ ..

Comment: Try fiddling with https://regex101.com/r/rH6zH6/2.

Comment: See [`^\S+\s+(\d+).*?\s+\S+\s+\/file\/(\d+)\/\S*\s+\S+\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gH0bW9/1)

Comment: <?php
 
exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl fullstatus', $output); foreach ($output as $output )  { 

preg_match_all('@^\d-\d+\h+(\d+)\h+\d+/\d+/\d+\h+[A-Z]\h+\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+\d+\h+\d+\h+\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h+(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\h+[\w/.:]+\h+[A-Z]+\h+/file/(\d+)/.*@si', $output, $url) ; 
foreach($url[1] as $output )
{
    echo $output ;
} 


}



?>
This gives me also an empty response. Maybe because of the spaces, there is only one inbetween.

Comment: Sample output: 0-15 9785 0/120/5766 W 2.51 1046 0 0.0 11.74 10135.46 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/786252433434128/ HTTP/1.1 1-15 15844 0/100/6326 W 2.12 1654 0 0.0 23.37 11295.31 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/762070024199783/ HTTP/1.1 2-15 15876 0/40/6154 R 1.81 0 161 0.0 186.47 16999.30 14.167.55.213 3-15 9153 0/130/6392 W 2.74 699 0 0.0 23.80 13756.44 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/404629577556625/ HTTP/1.1   From the first output value.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your question? Would be interested to know how this evolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'll avoid the "at least try..." spiel. But here's a start for you:

```
/^\d{1,}-\d{2,} (\d+) .+ \/file\/(\d+)\/ .+$/
```

Basically we're looking for your starting ID (im guessing its an ID) such as `1-15` then capturing the number after. Then looking for `/file/.../` and capturing the number there too.

You will need to alter this for all you data as we only have 3 lines to work on. Nor is it perfect. But hopefully enough to get you on your way...

https://regex101.com/r/dE8lE2/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern that I like because it is reusable in different contexts:
^(?:\S+\s+){1}(\S+\s+){1}(?:\S+\s+){11}.*?(\d+).*$

This says:

- ^ - 'From the beginning of the line'
- (?:\S+\s){1} - Consume one column without capturing - \S+ says 'get one or more non-space characters' and \s+ 'get one or more space characters'the parens and {1} are not strictly necessary but facilitate re-use in the event that you wanted to skip the first 'n' columns
- (\S+\s) - Capture the value in the next column (column 2)
- (?:\S+\s){11} - Skip the next 11 columns
- .*?(\d+) - consume the minimum number of any character up to but not including a number; then capture one or more successive numbers
- .*$ - identify the remainder of characters until the end of the line ($) - this is not strictly necessary but useful if wanting to use a find/replace tool to see result of line transformation

The captured parts of the pattern are then the 2nd column and the numeric part of the 14th column (there are multiple ways to capture the numeric part as noted in at least one other answer).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
[\d-]+\s+(\d+).+?(?:GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).+?/([^/]+)/?\s+HTTP[^\s]+
```

[Regex live demo](https://regex101.com/r/sU9wH9/3)

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/4cnjI)

Comment: <?php
 
exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl fullstatus', $output); foreach ($output as $str )  {  

preg_match_all('~(?m)^[\d-]+\s+(\d+).+(?:GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).+?/([^/]+)/?\s~', $str, $matches); 

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $id ) {  
    echo $id."\n".$matches[2][$key]."\n" ;
}

}


?>

gives me an empty response, maybe because there are only one space in between.

Comment: This is a sample output from $output: 0-15 9785 0/120/5766 W 2.51 1046 0 0.0 11.74 10135.46 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/786252433434128/ HTTP/1.1 1-15 15844 0/100/6326 W 2.12 1654 0 0.0 23.37 11295.31 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/762070024199783/ HTTP/1.1 2-15 15876 0/40/6154 R 1.81 0 161 0.0 186.47 16999.30 14.167.55.213 3-15 9153 0/130/6392 W 2.74 699 0 0.0 23.80 13756.44 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/404629577556625/ HTTP/1.1

Comment: You should add your **EXACT** input to your question. @Tom

Comment: still empty respone, could you maybe try it with the exec command as well, if you have a running server with apache? i mean your code is working yes, however it seems something with the foreach loop (from the exec command) will not correspond..

Comment: I provided you with two workarounds for your two different inputs (with live demos). So if you don't get expected results, either your inputs are not exactly the same or you are not correctly implementing things. Really I am done at this point. You should only play a little more with codes in my examples to make them work at your case. @Tom

Comment: Hello, yes actually as a workaround i now use filegetcontents (where the first output of the command echo the result on another url on my site) and than use your code which works. So something with the foreach loop prevented this to work. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad that it worked. You could mark my answer as accepted or up-vote it if it was helpful. @Tom

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to do it:

```
preg_match_all('/\S+\s+(\d+).*?file\/(\d+).*?$/m', $output, $url) ;

foreach(array_combine($url[1], $url[2]) as $num1 => $num2) {
    echo "$num1 $num2\n";
};
```

Output for the sample data:

```
20241 192493511503562
6252 720658522052690
9649 512530584447085
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/611677)

Comment: mhm still receive an empty response.. does somebody can test this out wiht a running server? the full code with apache.. maybe it is because of the previous foreach loop:  this is what i have so far: <?php
 
exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl fullstatus', $output); foreach ($output as $str )  {

preg_match_all('@[0-9] (.*?) [0-9]*[/]file[/](.*?)HTTP*@si', $str, $matches); 

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $id ) {  
    echo $id."\n".$matches[2][$key]."\n" ;
}

}





?>

Comment: It must be you are not giving the exact data. Pasting in comments does not help. The format in comments hides  newlines and other white space. Of  course I ran this on a server. The link is in my answer. I suggest you make such a fiddle yourself which illustrates the problem.

Comment: did you try it also with the apachectl fullstatus command, i might think it is because of the foreach loop (the first foreach loop).

Comment: @[0-9] (.*?) [0-9]*[/](.*?)@si this gives me those example: 1005 GET 8820 GET 21881 GET, instead of the GET i need the file inbetween (/file/VALUE/) ... the PID are different on this answer

Comment: with this foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $id ) {  
    echo $id."\n".$matches[2][$key]."\n" ;
}

Comment: Add an echo $str just before the preg-match to be sure it is something expected.

Comment: Then I suggest you take that value and put the code on http://eval.in without the exec, but just with the hardcoded value you just got now. Then see if that works or not. This problem is not related with the apachectl command since you have the $str content. We just need to get the exact same string including any funny chars.

Comment: i already tried this, yes it is working, just for the for one loop. https://eval.in/611712 . Something on the foreach loop (the first one) seems to be the failure.

Comment: Exclude that possibility by ouputting the string after that first loop. If you still have the expected string there then the cause cannot be in code that comes before it.

Comment: Maybe your PHP service went weird. Tried a restart?

Answer (score -2):

This might help you.

```
/\d+\-\d+\s+(\d+).+\/file\/(\d+)/g
```

test link :
    https://regex101.com/r/kM3qR3/1

php:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\-\d+\s+(\d+).+\/file\/(\d+)/g', $output, $url) ; 
foreach($url[1] as $k => $output )
{
    echo $output . ',' . $url[2][$k];
}
```

***edit:***

phpfiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0be40cc84a0f02b89a9181aef63c3706e607e7ab

Comment: <?php
 
exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl fullstatus', $output); foreach ($output as $output )  { 

preg_match_all('/\d+\-\d+\s+(\d+).+\/file\/(\d+)/g', $output, $url) ; 
foreach($url[1] as $k => $output )
{
    echo $output . ',' . $url[2][$k];
} 



}


}


?>

Comment: This is my full code, still not working... Sample output: 0-15 9785 0/120/5766 W 2.51 1046 0 0.0 11.74 10135.46 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/786252433434128/ HTTP/1.1 1-15 15844 0/100/6326 W 2.12 1654 0 0.0 23.37 11295.31 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/762070024199783/ HTTP/1.1 2-15 15876 0/40/6154 R 1.81 0 161 0.0 186.47 16999.30 14.167.55.213 3-15 9153 0/130/6392 W 2.74 699 0 0.0 23.80 13756.44 182.237.133.117 domain.com:443 GET /file/404629577556625/ HTTP/1.1

Comment: @Tom first of all check preg_math code to verify it is working as you want

Comment: the sample output is from the first output statement. and there is one } too much. however is there no chance to have this @[0-9] (.*?) [0-9]*/(.*?)/@si  just changed?

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in PHP.

Comment: @chris85 yes there is.

Comment: No, there isnt. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php Test your code, https://eval.in/611603. `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'g'`. Additionally your 2nd and 3rd parameters of `preg_match_all` are inverted. 2nd param is input, third is output.

Comment: yes already changed this with @ @si , and normal with / / but still no result.

Comment: @chris85 you can check fiddle.

Comment: Your answer should have all the code. This answer has multiple errors.